Why does -fsigned-zeros inhibit this optimization?
Take this expression for float x:
float x8 = x * x * x * x * x * x * x * x

Clang knows to reduce it to 3 multiplications (BTW gcc doesn't), essentially:
float x2 = x * x;
float x4 = x2 * x2;
float x8 = x4 * x4;

I thought -fassociative-math would be enough to enable this optimization , but surprisingly it is enabled only with -fassociative-math + -fno-signed-zeros :
https://www.compiler-explorer.com/z/81586q33q
Is there a real reason for this which I'm missing?

The GCC documentation says, for -fassociative-math, “This option requires that both -fno-signed-zeros and -fno-trapping-math be in effect.” That suggests it simply is not enabled at all unless you also enable -fno-signed-zeros. The documentation also indicates that -fassociative-math can change the signs of zeros, so the design rationale there may be “We are not going to enable -fassociative-math unless you have told us it is okay that the signs of zeros may change.”

@EricPostpischil Thank you! But can you see how can fassociative-math change the signs of zeros?   (equivalent to the original question)

Sorry I think I get it, something like -0 + 1 - 1.   The single flag -fassociative-math controls both addition and multiplication.
